# Speed of chrome.storage.sync.get vs get from chrome.storage.local

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-storage

I'm developing a Chrome extension whose functionality relies on options, so I'm calling the main function is called as a callback after fetching options from Chrome storage.

In testing on my machine, I've had faster results from using chrome.storage.sync.get, rather than chrome.storage.local.get, but it's still slowing up the page load quite a bit. I wondered if that might be just my machine, and typically local.get would be faster, or if there's a way to cache these settings to be more easily accessible.

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: It's an asynchronous API so it doesn't slow down your page. It can take more or less time depending on other tasks the browser is busy with. Like other extensions, pages etc. Anyway, if you want to display the data as soon as possible, you'll have to use the good old synchronous `window.localStorage` as a stringified cache of the most critical stuff you absolutely need to display in the first paint frame.

Comment: Yeah, the reason it was slowing down the page is I specifically had the main function running as a callback after it returned, because I'm an idiot. :P
Wonderful. Thanks!